# Add € sign to data labels in bubble chart - ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bubble-chart

This is the head of my data:

```
structure(list(asutus = c("Eesti Draamateater", "Eesti Draamateater", 
"Eesti Noorsooteater", "Eesti Noorsooteater", "Rahvusooper Estonia", 
"Rahvusooper Estonia", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", 
"Sakala Teatrimaja", "Vene Teater", "Vene Teater"), liik = c("Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", 
"Teatrite tugiteenused", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", "Teatrite tugiteenused", 
"Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", "Teatrite tugiteenused", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", 
"Teatrite tugiteenused", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", 
"Teatrite tugiteenused"), tooandja_kulu_aastas = c(131980, 455701, 
103401, 257137, 124755, 1081211, 49147, 188658, 24373, 105234, 
236232)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

My colors:

```
prx_col_palette <- function(){
  c("#E69F00",
    "#56B4E9",
    "#009E73",
    "#F0E442",
    "#0072B2",
    "#D55E00",
    "#CC79A7")
}
prx_cols <- prx_col_palette()
```

My bubble chart:

```
ggplot(palgad_joonisele2,
       aes(x = liik, 
           y = asutus,
           colour = liik,
           size = tooandja_kulu_aastas)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = tooandja_kulu_aastas), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+ 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(14, 37)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = prx_cols)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

This is what my plot looks like right now:

[image]

My question is - how to get Euro signs (€) before the numbers on the graph and format the data labels that they would be more readable since they are labor costs. For example like this: €10 000 not 10000 or like €10,000?

Comment: See `?scales::label_dollar`. You can choose the prefix and suffix. The euro symbol could be `prefix = "\u20ac"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package `scales` to change the `geom_text` label. The only change is

```
label = dollar(tooandja_kulu_aastas, prefix = "\u20ac")
```

the rest of the code is exactly the same as in the question.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

prx_col_palette <- function(){
  c("#E69F00",
    "#56B4E9",
    "#009E73",
    "#F0E442",
    "#0072B2",
    "#D55E00",
    "#CC79A7")
}
prx_cols <- prx_col_palette()

ggplot(palgad_joonisele2,
       aes(x = liik, 
           y = asutus,
           colour = liik,
           size = tooandja_kulu_aastas)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = dollar(tooandja_kulu_aastas, prefix = "\u20ac")), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+ 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(14, 37)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = prx_cols)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sprintf("€%0.2f")` command to label the values with euro in this code:

```
palgad_joonisele2 <- structure(list(asutus = c("Eesti Draamateater", "Eesti Draamateater", 
                          "Eesti Noorsooteater", "Eesti Noorsooteater", "Rahvusooper Estonia", 
                          "Rahvusooper Estonia", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", 
                          "Sakala Teatrimaja", "Vene Teater", "Vene Teater"), liik = c("Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", 
                                                                                       "Teatrite tugiteenused", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", "Teatrite tugiteenused", 
                                                                                       "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", "Teatrite tugiteenused", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", 
                                                                                       "Teatrite tugiteenused", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", "Kinnisvara haldus ja korraldus", 
                                                                                       "Teatrite tugiteenused"), tooandja_kulu_aastas = c(131980, 455701, 
                                                                                                                                          103401, 257137, 124755, 1081211, 49147, 188658, 24373, 105234, 
                                                                                                                                          236232)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                       "data.frame"))


prx_col_palette <- function(){
  c("#E69F00",
    "#56B4E9",
    "#009E73",
    "#F0E442",
    "#0072B2",
    "#D55E00",
    "#CC79A7")
}
prx_cols <- prx_col_palette()

ggplot(palgad_joonisele2,
       aes(x = liik, 
           y = asutus,
           colour = liik,
           size = tooandja_kulu_aastas)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("€%0.2f", tooandja_kulu_aastas)), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 2.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+ 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(14, 37)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = prx_cols)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach using `paste0('€',formatC(tooandja_kulu_aastas, big.mark=',', format = 'fg'))`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)


prx_col_palette <- function(){
  c("#E69F00",
    "#56B4E9",
    "#009E73",
    "#F0E442",
    "#0072B2",
    "#D55E00",
    "#CC79A7")
}
prx_cols <- prx_col_palette()

palgad_joonisele2 %>% 
  mutate(my_label = paste0('€',formatC(tooandja_kulu_aastas, big.mark=',', format = 'fg'))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = liik, 
           y = asutus,
           colour = liik,
           size = tooandja_kulu_aastas)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = my_label), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+ 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(14, 37)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = prx_cols)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]